# Execute all "py" in subfolders python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie and have spent a lot of time. I need your help.

I have a a folder structure and each folder has a script called "MafeV1.py".

I would like to go through this whole folder structure and subfolders and run consecutively all the "MafeV1.py".

I will be grateful for your collaboration.

I have tried this but it did not work

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob('/mydir/**/MafeV1.py', recursive=True)

for f in files:
    try:
        open()
    except OSError as e:
        print("Error: %s : %s" % (f, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
subprocess.run(["python", f])
```

See more options in https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html